# Visual studio 2017 c# design view fail to load after rename

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a winform app.

The design view worked well until I renamed the Form1.cs to FormMain.cs.

The program itself is ok. It can be compiled with no error and it runs well(with right form). But visual studio keep warning me that there are mistakes in FormMain.cs. It seems that FormMain class in FormMain.Designer.cs is totally ignore as it alerts "InitializeComponent(); is not defined."

And the design view goes blank as if the form was just newly-created.

IntelliSense tells me the origin(not yet renamed) Designer.cs is not found.

Now if I try to create anything on the blank form, the code is directly written in FormMain.cs.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like Winforms, not WPF...

Comment: Do a find and replace to locate all instances of "Form1" and change to "FormMain".  My guess is you've missed some, possibly in the design partial classes.

Comment: sorry for wpf, winform indeed, there is definitely no Form1, I've checked for several times. If so it shound't be compiled successfully.

Comment: your compile will give you an error, just double click in it and then you will open the page with the error, you can delete the error line in that page

Comment: Rename it back to Form1.  Now right-click "Form1" in the text editor and choose Rename.  Which ensures that the designer.cs file gets updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio 2019, I was following the C# WPF tutorial from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-wpf?view=vs-2019). Along the way, there is a step wherein you rename `MainWindow.xaml` to `Greetings.xaml`. When I did this, the design view was gone. Restarting Visual Studio fixes the design view. Of course, save your files before restarting.

Comment: I just ran in to this on a new .NET6 WPF application in VS2022. The problem still exists and restarting VS is still the solution. I am disappoint.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the form and adding it again to the solution fixes this issue. Here's how you can do:

Right click on the FormMain in the solution explorer and "Exclude From Project". Now right-click on the solution and click Add -> Existing Item and select the FormMain.cs from the same solution folder.